# How populate a javascript object from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm very new to JavaScript. I just started a few weeks ago. I'm trying to populate a js object 'self.data' from a json file. I thought I had it but it doesn't seem to actually populate it, as I can't access any of the key:value pairs.

```
self.data = {
    
};

self.util = {
    ajax: function(url, funcSuccess) {
        self.ctx.$.ajax(url, {
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                funcSuccess(data);
            }
        });
    },
};

self.getData = function () {
    var obj;
    self.util.ajax("./data.json",function(data){
        obj = {...data.manufacturer}; 
        self.data["color"] = obj.model[0];
        self.data["year"] =  obj.model[1];
        self.data["miles"] =  obj.model[2];

        self.data["turbo"] = obj.features[0];
        self.data["rims"] = obj.features[1];  
        self.data["heated_seats"] = obj.features[2];      
    })
    
};

self.onInit = function () {
    self.getData(); 
    
};
```

I have also tried making each member in the self.data and not assigning it any real value. When I do console.log(self.data) an empty array is shown but when I click on it, it expands and I see all of the values that I have assigned.

EDIT1:
When I do

```
console.log(self.data)
```

from my HTML page the console will show the following:

```
v{}
 >color
 >year
 >miles
 >turbo
 >rims
 >heated_seats
```

But I can't access any of those objects through my code.

Comment: are you getting `console.log(obj)` ?@CoolGuyJones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the data in correct way to self.data. You can use data only when your self.util.ajax("./data.json"..) is successful.

Also,

- It could be possible you are using the variable before it has been assigned
- or check the scope of varable as well.

If your `obj = {...data.manufacturer};` have proper data. then put console.log(self.data) after `self.data["heated_seats"] = obj.features[2];`, you will surely get the result on console.

**Sample:**

```
self.getData = function () {
    var obj;
    self.util.ajax("./data.json",function(data){
        obj = {...data.manufacturer}; 
        self.data["color"] = obj.model[0];
        self.data["year"] =  obj.model[1];
        self.data["miles"] =  obj.model[2];

        self.data["turbo"] = obj.features[0];
        self.data["rims"] = obj.features[1];  
        self.data["heated_seats"] = obj.features[2];  
        console.log(self.data);    
    })
    
};
```

Comment: Ok yeah when I put the console.log() after all of that it works fine. Now I'm wondering how I translate that over to me HTML as I'll need to display that info on different parts of the page.

Comment: you can try some modular approach. in which you can update the UI section once you have the data. there are multiple ways to handle this. things that we want to achieve is render HTML once we have data. You can creaate some method and bind HTML once you have all information. So, use some 2 way binding libraries.

Comment: Ooohhhh so something like Vue could achieve this?

Comment: you can achieve using jquery/javascript as well but that's up to u. yeah, try using vue, angular or react libraries

Answer (score 0):

First you should verify that the url is actually returning the result you expect.  Either inspect the network request in a browser debugger or pop the url into your browser directly.

If you are receiving a response and If the server is not setting the appropriate content type header on the response (it should be setting a response header of application/json) then jquery ajax is going to give you a string containing the data instead of an object.  If you can't or dont want to configure the server then you can just call JSON.parse on the result yourself.

If the server is not returning a 200 response containing json then you have a server side issue or your url is wrong.

Comment: I am getting the correct data back, it's just not populating self.data. Say I do something like this in my html file ```console.log(self.data["color"]``` or I use dot notation, it will say it is undefined. See my original post for what happens when I console.log(self.data)